# How to correctly set up model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, associations

I want a `user` to be able to create and save or choose an existing `client` to add to an invoice. There can only be one `client` per invoice.

I currently have 3 models `users` `invoices` and `items`
I am using a simple `has_many` relationship currently but I am getting confused now that I want to add a new table `clients`. I was hoping I could get some advice on what association to use.

My current associations

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :invoices

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :items, :dependent => :destroy

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :invoice
```

So I was thinking to do something simple like adding `has_many :clients`
to `users`, add `has_one :client` to `invoices` and add the table `clients`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :invoices
has_many :clients

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to : user

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :items, :dependent => :destroy
has_one :client
```

Would this work? Is there a better way?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: updated question for clarity

Answer (score 1):

It is very rare that you will use `has_one`. In your case the following models make more sense:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoices
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :client
  has_many :items, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoices
  has_many :items, through: :invoices
end
```